# C# String.Format - Invalid input string

Tags: c#, string.format

I have a MVC3 HtmlHelper extension like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ShowInfoBar(this HtmlHelper helper, string message, InfoMessageType messageType)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">$(document).ready(function () { gtg.core.showInfoBar('{0}', '{1}'}; );</script>", message, messageType.ToString().ToLower()));
    }
```

The value of `message` is `"The product "Product Name" was saved successfully."`

The value of `messageType` is `info`.

It keeps saying `Input string was not in the correct format.`

I am stuck??

Comment: Is there an error if you just enter the string without using the String.Format() method on it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On every brace that isn't a token you must double - so

```
function() {{
```

Etc

Also - consider XSS here - is `message` escaped correctly for inserting into JavaScript?

Comment: Could you point me somewhere to learn about this a little more? Thanks!

Comment: Which, XSS? Anywhere. Wikipedia would be a start. All you'd need is `a ' message " with ' quotes " in` to test it (although full escaping is more than just quotes)

Comment: Excellent mention of whether the method parameter is escaped for JavaScript correctly.

Comment: So this is what it outputs: `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () { gtg.core.showInfoBar('The product "Rich Classic Chocolate" was saved successfully.', 'info'); });</script>` Is this escaped properly?

Comment: @Sam - I can't answer that without seeing what it does with a product name of `O'Neills' "oatey" Hobnobs`

Comment: @Marc - This is what it outputs: `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () { gtg.core.showInfoBar('O'Neills' "oatey" Hobnobs', 'info'); });</script>` and the script does not do what it is supposed to do. In the console of Chrome I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: @Sam right; so currently it is broken. Now imagine that I carefully created a product name like `'); stealYourCookiesAndPostThemSomewhere(); //` - and I've hacked your login - hence XSS. The *simplest* option is to write the data to a hidden element somewhere and read it out. Another option is to use something like JavascriptSerializer to write JSON (which will then be escaped). A plain JSON escape would be welcome, too.

Comment: @Marc - So would you have to have access to the server to do that? I mean you would have to have access to input that from somewhere right? So in this case, while it is an XSS, this is a backend manager for a site, so I would assume it is not a very high probability, but if this were available to the public user it could be a serious issue?

Comment: @Sam it all depends on context of course - you could argue that simply not being able to correctly handle `O'Neills' biscuits` is enough of a bug. But also don't underestimate the amount of evil committed *internally* to an organisation (especially shortly after a bad pay review, etc) - it isn't just the unwashed public that are capable of doing harm.

Comment: @Marc - I totally feel you on that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10):

Escape your squiggly brackets {{ }} in the format string

```
String.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">$(document).ready(function () {{ gtg.core.showInfoBar('{0}', '{1}'); }});</script>", message, messageType.ToString().ToLower())
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the curly braces:

`{{` and `}}`

```
String.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">$(document).ready(function () {{ gtg.core.showInfoBar('{0}', '{1}'}}; );</script>", 
              message, messageType.ToString().ToLower())
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used the bracket for JsonP formatting. JsonP requires a  '{' too. By escaping the { like this: '{{', my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as below, and its working.

```
string.Format(@"ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {{ Your function.
```