# Variable Name to be used for building a relationship in neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

In the code snippet below, I need to create a Relation with the Contents from a Variable.

In the code snippet, sRelationName is a variable, but as expected the relation that is created is created as ":sRelationName" because of the ":" sign.

Any ideas on what to do to create relation based on contents of a variable

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(en1:Entity)", "(en2:Entity)")
    .Where((Entity en1) => en1.EntityName == sParentEntity)
    .AndWhere((Entity en2) => en2.EntityName == sChildEntity)
    .CreateUnique("en1-[:sRelationName]->en2")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher won't accept relationship types as query parameters. This should be a feature provided by the `Neo4jClient` library, but since it is missing you must do this by yourself in your logic code. For this you can use string concatenation or `String.Format`:

```
.CreateUnique(String.Format("en1-[:{0}]->en2", sRelationName))
```

This is of course a simple case, so remember that if you have Json brackets in your expression, then you must escape them (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7097199/1697320)) in order to use `String.Format` like this:

```
.CreateUnique(
    String.Format(
        "en1-[:{0} {{ category: {{category_name}} }}]->en2",
        sRelationName
    )
)
```

Just remember not to use user input as the value of `sRelationName` variable. Otherwise you'll have injection vulnerability if you don't escape it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! that worked. Sure, I will not use user input for the variable. Its more to describe more than one relation based on application meta data.