# How to append double quote character to a string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a C# property as a string as part of an experiment, but I'm getting the error "Input string was not in the correct format".

Is this because of the `quote`?

How can I properly append the double quote character to the string?

this is the code:

```
string quote = "\"";
string propName = "MyPropName";
string propVal = "MyPropVal";
string csProperty = string.Format("public string {0} { get { return {1}; } }", propName, quote + propVal + quote);
```

Comment: its your curly braces - they need escaped: `{{` and `}}`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097199/c-sharp-string-format-invalid-input-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the braces (by doubling) that are not part of the format mask:

```
string csProperty = string.Format("public string {0} {{ get {{ return {1}; }} }}", propName, quote + propVal + quote);
```